# PHP Array outputs as a string

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have the wordpress code below to output an array of integers, but when I try to access the array values it appears to not be an array but rather a string

```
$values = get_post_custom_values('colleagues', 123);

print_r($values); //This Outputs Array ([0]=>["418","5555"])

$arr = $values[0];
foreach($arr as $val)
{
   echo $val;   
}
```

The only output of the above foreach is ["418","5555"], I'd expect to see 2 values so it must not be an array.

Comment: Have you tried `is_array()`?

Comment: Try `var_dump($values)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I initialise `$values` with an array containing a string like this:

```
<?php
$values = ['["418","5555"]'];
print_r($values); //This Outputs Array ([0]=>["418","5555"])


$arr = $values[0];
foreach($arr as $val)
{
   var_dump($val);   
}
```

I get the same output from the print_r.  And a Php warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

So perhaps your suspicion holds true.

If however I write values like this:

```
$values = [["418","5555"]];
print_r($values);
```

I get output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 418 [1] => 5555 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$values[0]` looks like an array but isn't. It's stored as a string.

We know that because of the output of `print_r()`.

```
print_r($values); //This Outputs Array ([0]=>["418","5555"])
```

Notice that `print_r` recognised `$values` as an array but there's not a similar identifier next to `[0] => ...`.

As of PHP 5.4, square brackets became shorthand for an array so it's easy to see the confusion.

I'd suggest looking at how those values are being saved in the first place and then reversing the process.